# breeze : orderBy ICollection count or length

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, breeze

I have a c# class like this :

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class myTable
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Title{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<Thing> Things{ get; set; }
}
```

in the client side i want to get all the entities 'myTable' ordered by their 'Things' Count.

i tried :

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(resourceName).orderBy('things.length');`

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(resourceName).orderBy('things.Length');`

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(resourceName).orderBy('things.count');`

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(resourceName).orderBy('things.Count');`

none was a good query , how can i order the 'myTable' entities by their 'things' count or length.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the  [OData Query URL spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/) supports the use of functions in the ordering specification ... and neither does Breeze.

I think you'll either have to to that on the server (with a special controller endpoint) or in  memory on the client.

Sorry about that.